# Smart Contract send to ETH addresses in CSV?

Tags: transactions

Does anyone know if it's possible to send tokens from smart contract to ETH addresses you have in CSV spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Python scripted tool for exactly this purpose:

https://ico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#distribute-tokens

Comment: Thanks Mikko. Are you available to program something like this? I would be interested in hiring you for this. I sent you an email.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate and broadcast a transaction for each target address.